# Custom error page for a specific domain in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, custom-error-pages

I know that creating error pages in app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception is the way to override the error pages but I'd like to do it for a specific domain.

Is that possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to implements an [Exception Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) and inject them the request for intercept the domain info

Comment: Can i post as an answer so you can close the question?